# Sampling music objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I’m trying to find a way to sampling an audio file in objective-c. The task seems to be easy I just want to get 30 seconds of stereo audio (mp3 files) and save to a separate file. I don’t want to play them. And the code to save the file is OK. I know that there is a data property of AVAudioPlayer with the audio information, but I don’t know how to get 30 seconds of this data.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

- (void)configureAudioPlayer {
    NSURL *audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DemoSong" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    NSError *error;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [_audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the AVPlayer, you need an AVAsset and an AVAssetExportSession. You may want to look at AVComposition too.

But I think that the Apple technical note [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1730/_index.html) answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.